# How to get public ip address from AWS with Ruby SDK

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sdk

I'm very newbie with AWS.

I would like to get the public IP address from Ruby SDK but can't find how to get it.

> require 'aws-sdk'
>
> ec2 = Aws::EC2::Resource.new(region: 'us-west-2')
>
> i = ec2.instance('i-XXXXXX')

with this two command, I only get state and code.

**How to get the public IP address since it usually changes when we shutdown the instance??**

Thank in advance

Comment: maybe this is ugly, but you can do a curl call. like this; curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4

Comment: Thanks for the response.
 yes with that solution we can get a public IP address. 

I try to use a programmatic way to handle it. I can found in Java SDK but can't find with Ruby SDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have your `Instance` object, in your case the `i` variable, use the `public_ip_address` attribute to reference the public IP address of your EC2 instance.

Example:

```
require 'aws-sdk'
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Resource.new(region: 'us-west-2')
i = ec2.instance('i-XXXXXX')
publicIp = i.public_ip_address
```

Docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/EC2/Instance.html#public_ip_address-instance_method

Comment: Thanks. this is Newbie fault. 

I get lost when I print "I.state" and saw the type is INstanceState so I think it didn't have public ip address.

this help me a lot to clarify how it work

Cheers